# How to pull a record with AJAX 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

On my site I have a simple model called Feed.

I want to make a link/button that will pull the Feed record with id=5 (for example) using AJAX.

The record that has been pulled should be displayed in a partial.

How can I do that ?

Thanks,

Oded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you could do sth like this:

In your controller you must respond to ajax request using the respond_to :js. Then you could either render directyl javascript which will be executed on your site, or the way I suggest you, to render json and parse it on the client side.

class YourController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    @model = YourModel.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json  {
        render :json => @model.to_json
      }
    end
  end
```

On the client side, just bind a click handler and then fetch the data using the path to your controller:

```
  $("#your_link_id").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('/path_to_your_controller', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

The code is not tested, but it should work in that way.

Note: the console.log works with firefox but not with safari, try using firebug for console output.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of long for a SO answer, but this should get you going:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails-2.1/rails-and-ajax.htm

That's where I got started with AJAX on RAILS